# Keep Getting Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql

Will not run kept getting the error.I have change the code around different ways but keep getting the same error. Anyone have any suggestion

```
SELECT *
From (
Select      R.CREATED as Created, 

        Case WHEN R.SR_AREA = 'OB 1st' THEN 'OB Res 2nd'  When R.SR_AREA = 'OB Res 2nd' THEN 'OB Res 3rd' Else R.SR_AREA END as [SR_AREA] 

FROM        S_SRV_REQ AS R WITH (NOLOCK) 

WHERE       (R.INS_PRODUCT = 'Pending OB') AND 
        (R.CREATED BETWEEN @StartDate AND dateadd(d,1,@EndDate)) AND 
        (R.SR_AREA in('OB 1st','OB Res 2nd','OB Res 3rd')) AND 
        (R.RESOLUTION_CD = 'No Answer') 

UNION



SELECT      TOP (100) PERCENT R.SR_AREA, 
        R.RESOLUTION_CD 


FROM        S_SRV_REQ AS R WITH (NOLOCK) 

WHERE       ((R.INS_PRODUCT = 'Pending OB') AND (R.LAST_UPD BETWEEN @StartDate AND dateadd(d,1,@EndDate)) AND 
        (R.SR_AREA in('Inbound', 'OB Res 3rd')) OR (R.RESOLUTION_CD <> 'No Answer'))
```

Comment: your select * from ( has no matching parenthesis

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis.  The easy way to check for that kind of error is to use an editor that highlights the match for delimiters like that.  Notepad++ is one possibility.

Comment: Thanks That worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a last `)` at the end of your statement.

```
 Select * From (
           .....
               ) <---
```

Answer (score 0):

open ( should match closing ) check for that I see that you have one unclosed (